# How do I install gtk-v4l on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: apt, ppa, webcam

I'm running latest `Ubuntu 16.10` desktop operating system.

How do I install `gtk-v4l` package to control my webcam settings?

I'm getting the following errors during `apt-get update`:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I was following this guide: [Webcam settings control on Ubuntu Linux operating system](http://www.techytalk.info/webcam-settings-control-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: That PPA doesn't support 16.10 because it hasn't been updated since 2010.

Comment: So the only program for webcam settings in Ubuntu is virtually non-existent? That makes me sad.

Comment: Modern alternatives seem to be v4l2ucp and qv4l2, both of which can be installed with apt. In my quick tests, qv4l2 seemed to work better

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install the mentioned package since the ppa you added does not have the release package for yaketty yet. So you can wait for a few weeks, it will probably be updated for the 16.10 release.

[image]

[PPA for libv4l v4l-utils](https://launchpad.net/~libv4l/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: That PPA isn't updated since 2010. A few more weeks won't make any difference.

Comment: @CelticWarrior It looks to me like there is still [development](https://launchpad.net/~libv4l/+archive/ubuntu/development) going on. Whether that will eventually equate to a Yaketty release remains to be seen,.

Comment: qv4l2 seems to be a better modern alternative

Comment: @Zach: That's what I was looking for